# How to change discord bot prefix using command (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I searched in StackOverflow already, founded it. But its not exactly what I want...

So please do not call this a duplicate :)

BTW here the code I'm using:

```
@client.command()
async def change_prefix(ctx, arg=None):
    if str(type(arg)) == "<class 'NoneType'>":
        await ctx.send("Please insert an argument...")
    else:
        client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = str(arg))
        command_prefix = str(arg)

        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Prefix set!",
        description = f"The bot prefix has been set to {arg}",
        color = discord.Color.red())

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author} at {current_time}")

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what are you trying to do? For changing prefixes you need to have a json file and all that.

Comment: Are you changing the `command_prefix` per guild or for the bot as a whole? Please edit your question accordingly to specify your needs.

Comment: Do `if arg == None` instead of `if str(type(arg)) == "<class 'NoneType'>"`.
It is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need a database to store the prefixes of different servers.

You are not meant to reinitialise the `Bot` class as you did in your code.

Store your prefixes in a database or elsewhere and make a `get_prefix` method and use it in your `Bot` class.

```py
async def get_prefix(bot, message):
  # you can do your database queries or things to get prefix. 
  # Finally, Just return prefix as str or list.
  return prefix
```

Then in your Bot class instance:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

This function would call upon every message so consider setting up a caching system to avoid database issues.

Comment: i dont really understand, can you show me a full code of it?